# why does `font-size : 0` somehow affects `line-height`

Tags: html, css, font-size

I have encountered a strange behavior in my design today.lets me show you my code first and then discuss it

```css
*,
*:after,
*::before {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
#all-content,
#content-outer,
#content-inner {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#content-inner {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="all-content">
  <div id="content-outer">
    <div id="content-inner">
      <div id="main-field">
        <div class="block">text</div>
        <div class="block">text</div>
        <div class="block">text</div>
        <div class="block">text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The thing is, with this code, there is a strange top padding applied to `#main-field` element.
There are two ways fix this.Either with applying a `line-height : 50px` rule to the `.block` class or change the font-size to something other than zero.
I want to know why is this happening since I've never encountered something strange like this behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And that's why you don't use that "hack" to remove space between block-inline elements. Even if the font size is 0 the text still has line height and probably not knowing how to behave it takes the space above the "block".

an easy solution if you still want to go with your code is to add:

```
vertical-align:top
```

to your block elements: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gqf4ex3k/1/)**

note: use float :)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you setting `font-size:0`? I'm guessing that you are trying one of the methods to remove white-space from between `inline-block` elements, but in that case, you need to specify `font-size:0` on the **parent** of the `inline-block` elements (which would be `#main-field`) in your case and then re-specify a font-size on the `inline-block` elements themselves.

Seeing how you are giving your elements a fixed width, then you probably don't need this hack at all and should just be using `float:left` and `display:block`.

Comment: the thing I wanted to do with `font-size : 0` is to prevent `collapsing margins` from happening since they are not empty blocks anymore